# Printing strings and photos

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, printing

I am trying to print some strings and photos. I have a panel which contains these controls. I am adding my code below. In the code, the `DataTable` contains the locations and size of the controls in string format.

The first is the image of the panel and the controls. Second image shows how `PrintPreviewDialog` shows the `document` after running the code.

The images and the code are posted below.

```
private void printMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    printPreviewDialog.Document = printDocument;
    printPreviewDialog.ShowDialog();
}

private void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
    var cvt = new FontConverter();

    int resX = PrnOpra.GetPrinterResolutionX(this.selectPrinterComboBox);
    int resY = PrnOpra.GetPrinterResolutionY(this.selectPrinterComboBox);
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;

    float scale = resX / ScrnRes;
    int bitmapHeight = 3517;
    int bitmapWidth = 1020;
    Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight);

    g.DrawImage(System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Application.StartupPath + @"\Resources\Item_Photos\" + dtItemsToBePrinted.Rows[u][c].ToString()),
                            pointItemPhoto.X, pointItemPhoto.Y, sizeItemPhoto.Width, sizeItemPhoto.Height);
    g.DrawString(dtItemsToBePrinted.Rows[u][c].ToString(),
                        cvt.ConvertFromString(font) as Font,
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                        pointFieldLabel.X, pointFieldLabel.Y,
                        new StringFormat());

    g.DrawImage((System.Drawing.Image)Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject(dtControls.Rows[u]["image"].ToString()),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["locationX"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["locationY"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["width"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["height"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat));

     g.DrawString(dtControls.Rows[u]["text"].ToString(),
                        cvt.ConvertFromString(dtControls.Rows[u]["font"].ToString()) as Font,
                        new SolidBrush(Color.Black),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["locationX"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                        float.Parse(dtControls.Rows[u]["locationY"].ToString(), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat),
                        new StringFormat());

}
```

[image]

[image]

As you can see in the images, the `Panel` is very well formatted but when printing the controls go at wrong places. What may be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what's wrong. I have saved wrong location values to `datatable`. I saved `Control.Top` to `Location.X` and `Contorl.Left` to `Location.Y`. ANd now printing very well.